# Sorting help. Insertion sort c#

Tags: c#, sorting, inheritance, polymorphism, insertion-sort

I have an Arraylist with a bunch of objects all of the same class(DistributedApps).

Constructor:

```
public Distributedapps(string appName, string devName, string description, double size, int estLife,double price, int downloads,int ratings,string distributor, double annLicenceFee, int maxUsers)
            :base(appName,devName,description,size,estLife,price,downloads,ratings)
```

I want the Insertionsort to sort this list(DeployedApps) descending on the App size(size)

```
public void DeployInsertionSortAppSizeDeployed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INSERTION SORT ON APP SIZE DEPLOYED!");
        int II;
        Distributedapps Temp, PrTemp;
        for (int IO = 1; IO <= (Count(DeployedApps) - 1); IO++)
        {
            Temp = (Distributedapps)DeployedApps[IO];
            II = IO;
            PrTemp = (Distributedapps)DeployedApps[II - 1];
            while ((II > 0) && (PrTemp.GetSize().CompareTo(Temp.GetSize()) <= 0)) 
            {
                DeployedApps[II] = DeployedApps[II - 1];
                II -=1;
            }
            DeployedApps[II] = Temp;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
    }
```

I try post pictures of list before and after if sort code looks fine and the bug isnt with it.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Does your sorter not work? Does it throw any exceptions? Does it not compile?

Comment: it doensnt sort correctly. The first two object from the top of the list are sorted wrongly. The rest of the list is sorted correctly.

Comment: `App size(size)` is a field of class `DistributedApps` right?

Comment: You're not updating `PrTemp` and `Temp` after swapping their position. I'm impressed your algorithm only gets the top 2 elements wrong...

Comment: But why you chose ArrayList for your DeployedApps? Why not simple List?

Comment: @Nolonar,shouldnt updating them right before the while loop work? This is whats messing with my mind.@Maris, the task said for any number of Apps. I dont know the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know internet i fixed it...

```
            Console.WriteLine("INSERTION SORT ON APP SIZE DEPLOYED!");
        Apps Temp, PrTemp;
        int II;
        for (int IO = 1; IO <= (Count(DeployedApps) - 1); IO++)
        {
            Temp = (Apps)DeployedApps[IO];
            PrTemp = (Apps)DeployedApps[IO - 1];
            II = IO;
            while ((II>0)&&(Temp.GetSize()>=PrTemp.GetSize()))
            {
                SwapDEP(II, II - 1);
                II = II - 1;
                if (II >= 1)
                {
                    Temp = (Apps)DeployedApps[II];
                    PrTemp = (Apps)DeployedApps[II - 1];
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
```